# How is the Guide RNA created for Crispr?

Tags: crispr, biomedical-engineering

It seems that to modify DNA a guide RNA and Cripr are introduced.

But I'm unable to understand how the Guide RNA is made or created.

Is it a simple method which can be done with simple lab equipment or is it complicated?

What is the equipment need to create it?